# Rank and edges in a combinatorial graph?

Tags: co.combinatorics, linear-algebra, graph-theory, matrices, enumerative-combinatorics

Fix a $d\in\mathbb N$ and consider the matrix $M\in\{0,1\}^{2^d\times d}$ of all $0/1$ vectors of length $d$. Consider the matrix $G\in\{0,1\}^{n\times n}$ whose $ij$ the entry is $0$ if inner product of $i$th row and $j$th row of $M$ is $0$ or else it is $1$ with $0$s on the diagonal (disregarding the inner product of $i$th row with itself).

Take the graph whose adjacency is given by $G$.

1. How many edges does this graph have?
2. Is it possible to give its rank over $\mathbb F_2$ and $\mathbb R$?

Comment: $n=2^d$, right?

Comment: True $n = 2^{d}$.

Comment: Shouldn't the rank of $M$ simply be $d$ (in $\Bbb R$ and $\Bbb F_2$), as the matrix contains the $d\times d$-identitiy matrix as a submatrix?

Comment: @M.Winter Don't know since we round.

Comment: @Turbo Wait, are you asking about the rank of the adjacency matrix or the rank of $M$?

Answer (score 2):

Concerning the edges, consider the following:

Let $v\in \smash{\{0,1\}^d}$ be a 0/1-vector with exactly $k$ zeroes. If $v\not=0$, there are exactly $2^k$ 0/1-vectors that have vanishing inner product with $v$. The vector $v=0$ is an exception, as it has zero inner product with itself (this would give a loop otherwise), and so we count only $\smash{2^d-1}$ neighbors for this one. The number of *non-edges* then is

$$\frac 12 \Big[\sum_{k=0}^d {d\choose k} 2^k-1\Big] = \frac {3^d-1}2.$$